# Is there a way to raise the form's on save event?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is there a way in VBA to detect when a user either clicks the pencil to save changes to a record, or presses the Save (Floppy disk) icon?

I am looking for ways to detect the event so I can confirm the save was accepted. I am using Access 2013 as the front-end to a SharePoint list and occasionally have users form save event fail. Sometimes they will be notified via the updated record conflicts dialog, but I want to programmatically confirm the change if possible.

Alternatively, I want to disable all save menus and icons in favor of using a button on the form.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [BeforeUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822421.aspx) event.
It occurs when the user intends to save a record by any means.
If intending to give them feedback of successful update use the [AfterUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822097.aspx) even.